# Saiku over Solr

Tags: saiku

I'm trying to use Saiku but the goal is: how to read a cube without build an "ad hoc" data structure (e.g. copy the existent data into the star schema). I know that a good pratice is to build a star schema during the night to analyse the data in the day after. But I think that a sort of degenerate dimensions is already stored into search engine like Solr. So why not use this real time data? Maybe the speedup from Solr search engine is neutralize from others bottleneck (reading CSV, Mondrian, MDX queries)?
I see that there is a presentation from Tom Barber at ApacheCon2014 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ch5qLNgMoE) that show the use of Saiku over Solr. Also there is the code into Github ( https://github.com/OSBI/optiq-solr ) for the adapter built on top of Optiq (now Calcite), but I do not find any example or documentation to use it. Anyone help me?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic here. However, you may find better luck [SoftwareRecs.SE](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.

Comment: Thank you @FrankerZ the question as you wrote is a bit off-topic because it can open a thread on the best practice for datawarehouse and datamart. In any case my intent was to find anyone who can suggest me how to build a successful integration between Saiku and the Solr search engine as datasource. These are two known software tools used by many developers and I wonder if anyone have a good suggestion to give. Thank you again for your hint and I try to move this topic in the right context.